# Shortening Code - DateTime & ELSE IF Statement - Making it Dynamic

Tags: c#, datetime, if-statement

I've got a big list of start and end DateTimes to calculate the user's Zodiac sign.

If the User's Birthday is between this date, the application spits out the relevant star sign.

I'm trying to cut my code down to that I can make it so that the Developer (me) can input additional Star Signs without having to specify a name and dates.

So for example:

```
(If UserBD >= DateStart && UserBD <= DateFinish)
{
  Console.WriteLine(“Your star sign is {0}”, StarSign);   
}
```

At the moment I have the following:

```
    DateTime AquariusStart = new DateTime(userBD.Year, 01, 20);
    DateTime AquariusEnd = new DateTime(userBD.Year, 02, 18);

    DateTime PiscesStart = new DateTime(userBD.Year, 02, 19);
    DateTime PiscesEnd = new DateTime(userBD.Year, 03, 20);


    if (userBD >= AquariusStart && userBD <= AquariusEnd)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your Star Sign is Aquarius!");
    }
    else if (userBD >= PiscesStart && userBD <= PiscesEnd)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your Star Sign is Pisces!");
    }
```

etc etc

What would I need to add in order to be able to make the code 'dynamic'?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Well you could work on the grounds that the end of one, is before the beginning of the next...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve the above using a various sections of the answers posted by other users in this question thread:

```
        List<StarSign> signList = new List<StarSign>()
        {
            new StarSign { startDate = new DateTime(userBD.Year, 01, 20), endDate = new DateTime(userBD.Year, 02, 18), signName = "Aquarius" },
            new StarSign { startDate = new DateTime(userBD.Year, 02, 19), endDate = new DateTime(userBD.Year, 03, 20), signName = "Pisces" },
            new StarSign { startDate = new DateTime(userBD.Year, 03, 21), endDate = new DateTime(userBD.Year, 04, 19), signName = "Aries" },
            new StarSign { startDate = new DateTime(userBD.Year, 04, 20), endDate = new DateTime(userBD.Year, 05, 20), signName = "Taurus" },
            new StarSign { startDate = new DateTime(userBD.Year, 05, 21), endDate = new DateTime(userBD.Year, 06, 20), signName = "Gemini" },
            new StarSign { startDate = new DateTime(userBD.Year, 06, 21), endDate = new DateTime(userBD.Year, 07, 22), signName = "Cancer" },
            new StarSign { startDate = new DateTime(userBD.Year, 07, 23), endDate = new DateTime(userBD.Year, 08, 22), signName = "Leo" },
            new StarSign { startDate = new DateTime(userBD.Year, 08, 23), endDate = new DateTime(userBD.Year, 09, 22), signName = "Virgo" },
            new StarSign { startDate = new DateTime(userBD.Year, 09, 23), endDate = new DateTime(userBD.Year, 10, 22), signName = "Libra" },
            new StarSign { startDate = new DateTime(userBD.Year, 10, 23), endDate = new DateTime(userBD.Year, 11, 21), signName = "Scorpio" },
            new StarSign { startDate = new DateTime(userBD.Year, 11, 22), endDate = new DateTime(userBD.Year, 12, 21), signName = "Sagittarius" },
            new StarSign { startDate = new DateTime(userBD.Year, 12, 22), endDate = new DateTime(userBD.Year + 1, 01, 19), signName = "Capricorn" }
        };
```

and

```
 for (int loopCounter = 0; loopCounter < signList.Count; loopCounter++)
 {
if (userBD >= signList[loopCounter].startDate && userBD <=  signList[loopCounter].endDate)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(signList[loopCounter].signName);
     break;
  }              
}
```

With the following class:

```
 class StarSign
    {
        public DateTime startDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime endDate { get; set; }
        public string signName { get; set; }
    }
```

Thanks to everyone for their help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to something like this

```
public class StarSign
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }
        public DateTime End { get; set; }
    }

    public class StarSignCalculator
    {
        public List<StarSign> Signs { get; set; }
        public StarSignCalculator()
        {
            Signs = new List<StarSign>();
            Signs.Add( new StarSign
            {
                Name = "Aquarius",
                Start = new DateTime(9999, 1,20),
                End = new DateTime(9999, 2, 18)
            } );
        }

        public StarSign GetStarSign( int month, int day )
        {
            var theDate = new DateTime( 9999, month, day );
            return Signs.FirstOrDefault( x => x.Start >= theDate && x.End <= theDate );
        }
    }
```

Call GetStartSign will return you the Sign. Remember to fill up all star signs in Signs list.

Comment: The zodiac Capricorn runs from December 22 til January 19. How will this code handle that?

Comment: For Capricorn, Use these dates
Start = new DateTime(9999, 12,22)
End = new DateTime(10000, 1, 19)

Comment: Could I use 'UserBD + 1' in order to fix the Capricorn star sign issue? All of the Years are == to the year that the User's Birthday is.

Comment: I used the class as described above, but then created the following:

<< LIST WITH OBJECTS >>

for (int loopCounter = 0; loopCounter < signList.Count; loopCounter++)
if (userBD >= signList[loopCounter].startDate && userBD <= signList[loopCounter].endDate) {
                               
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(signList[loopCounter].signName);
                        break;
                    }
}

Comment: I really dislike the hackyness of defining a sign as a `DateTime` (something which involves years, hours, seconds, milliseconds, a kind (UTC, Local, Unknwn) etc.) for both start and end. I can kind of look past abusing the `DateTime` api for setting a starting point, but I think you should model them as having a start and duration instead. Your models allows one to say the end comes before the bginning

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a Dictionary or something like that, to hold an unique star sign and its range of dates. so that you can select the sign based on the date range. and i have creates a new class `Timelimit` having two DateTime properties to denote the start date and end date.  The definition for the class will be as like the following:

```
class Timelimit
{
    public DateTime startDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime endDate { get; set; }
}
```

You can extend the the dictionary by adding new elements to them. Now consider the following code That will explain the rest :

```
DateTime userBD = DateTime.Now; // let today be the b'day

Dictionary<string, Timelimit> ZodiacSigns = new Dictionary<string, Timelimit>();
ZodiacSigns.Add("Aquarius", new Timelimit()
{
    startDate = new DateTime(userBD.Year, 01, 20),
    endDate = new DateTime(userBD.Year, 02, 18)
});
ZodiacSigns.Add("Pisces", new Timelimit()
{
    startDate = new DateTime(userBD.Year, 03, 19),
    endDate = new DateTime(userBD.Year, 05, 20)
});
// Hence populate the dictonary from the developer side

string star = ZodiacSigns.Where(x => 
                          userBD >= x.Value.startDate && 
                          userBD <= x.Value.endDate)
                         .FirstOrDefault().Key

 Console.WriteLine("Your Star Sign is {0}!", star);
```

Which will give the `Key` that will be the star sign for the corresponding range of dates.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a class `StarSign` as base class for types like `Aquarius` or `Pisces`. Then you can fill a sorted `List<StarSign>` and use LINQ to find the first.

The base type:

```
public class StarSign : IComparable<StarSign>
{
    public StarSign(string name, DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        if (start >= end) throw new ArgumentException("Start must be < end");
        this.Name = name;
        this.Start = start;
        this.End = end;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(StarSign other)
    {
        if (other == null) return 1;
        return Start.CompareTo(other.Start);
    }

    public bool IsStarSign(DateTime dt)
    {
        DateTime normalizedDate = new DateTime(this.Start.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day);
        return normalizedDate >= Start && normalizedDate <= End;
    }
}
```

Possible derived types:

```
public class Aquarius : StarSign
{
    public Aquarius() : base("Aquarius", new DateTime(1, 01, 20), new DateTime(1, 02, 18))
    {
    }
}
public class Pisces : StarSign
{
    public Pisces() : base("Pisces", new DateTime(1, 02, 19), new DateTime(1, 03, 20))
    {
    }
}
```

Then the remaining code is very simple and maintainable:

```
List<StarSign> starSigns = new List<StarSign> { new Aquarius(), new Pisces() };
starSigns.Sort(); // only needed once and only if it's not added in the correct order
```

...

```
StarSign starSign = starSigns.First(s => s.IsStarSign(userBD));
Console.WriteLine("Your Star Sign is {0}!", starSign.Name);
```

Comment: Why would you use inheritance (difference in behavior) to denote a difference in data?

Comment: @CodeCaster: just one approach, not needed though. It's only needed if you want to provide different methods or properties for specific star-signs.